# How to fix Index Out Of Range error

Tags: c#

How can I fix this error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

In this code:

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ID", "ID");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Firstname", "Firstname");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("MI", "MI");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Lastname", "Lastname");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Username", "Username");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Rights", "Rights");
c.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = c;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From Account";
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["ID"].Value = reader[0].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Firstname"].Value = reader[1].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["MI"].Value = reader[2].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Lastname"].Value = reader[3].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count -    1].Cells["Username"].Value = reader[7].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Rights"].Value      = reader[9].ToString();
}
c.Close();
```

Comment: What is the structure of Account table?

Comment: Which line throws the error?  What are the runtime states of the objects on that line?

Comment: Why not use dataBind?

Comment: @lexter provided an example of using databinding which is a simple solution to your problem. The reason you are getting an index out of range error is that you are referencing a row that hasn't been added yet so `Rows.Count-1` equals -1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to display data from database to `datagridview`? Why not use `databind`?

See my sample code:

```
string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=the directory or the path of your database";
string query = "SELECT * From Table Name";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: @AlfredSanz - what do you mean? ds is the `DataSet`

Answer (score 2):

The Rows collection has an 'Add' method that takes an object array.  It is definitely a simpler and more straightforward approach that the code sample in your question:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbs04kbx.aspx